# Attempted import error: 'styleFunctionSx' is not exported from '@material-ui/system'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting this error when attempting to npm start:

```
./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Box/Box.js
Attempted import error: 'styleFunctionSx' is not exported from '@material-ui/system'.

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

Does anyone know what the root cause and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same issue, its a version problem, just type npm i @material-ui/core at terminal, and it should solve the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).